# Counting the number of items in two mutually exclusive rows of categories

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, counting, google-sheets-query

Here is the sheet for testing: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11CoQ_PAtVNQBkbtnHH0xR4bhCQVU-pcz645h1akTQuA/edit?usp=sharing

I have a table like this:

```
| id | category | irrelevant |
|----|----------|------------|
| 1  | cat1     | FALSE      |
| 2  | cat2     | FALSE      |
| 3  |          | TRUE       |
| 4  | cat1     | FALSE      |
```

Each item has an ID and a category or, if it is considered irrelevant, it has no category and the column "irrelevant" is marked as TRUE.

What I would like to do is to write a formula that will return the number of items in each category plus a row with the number of irrelevant items. So in the case above the result would be:

```
| category   | number |
|------------|--------|
| cat1       | 2      |
| cat2       | 1      |
| irrelevant | 1      |
```

If I try something like:

`=QUERY(A1:C5,"select B,count(A) group by B")`

I get the correct numbers, but since "irrelevant" is not a category its cell is empty, so the result is:

```
| category | count id |
|----------|----------|
|          |        1 |
| cat1     |        2 |
| cat2     |        1 |
```

Notice the empty "B2" cell. Is there a way to rename it to "irrelevant" without altering the first table? One thing I tried was just to count the irrelevant items.

`=transpose(query(A1:C5, "select count(A) where C = TRUE label count(A) 'irrelevant'"))`

which returns me simply

```
| irrelevant | 1 |
```

And then altering slightly the first formula so it doesn't count the "empty" categories and finally joining both of them in an array:

```
={
  QUERY(A1:C5,"select B,count(A) where B <> '' group by B");
  TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A1:C5, "select count(A) where C = TRUE label count(A) 'irrelevant'"))
}
```

This returns me what I want for the example above

```
| category   | count id |
|------------|----------|
| cat1       |        2 |
| cat2       |        1 |
| irrelevant |        1 |
```

But this won't work if my original table doesn't have irrelevant items. Which can occur depending on the range I chose to query, so if I want to query a table like this:

```
| id | category | irrelevant |
|----|----------|------------|
|  5 | cat1     |    FALSE   |
|  6 | cat2     |    FALSE   |
|  7 | cat2     |    FALSE   |
|  8 | cat3     |    FALSE   |
```

The solution I found will not work. Any suggestions on how can I do that?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Just did. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF((B2:B="")*(C2:C<>""), "irrelevant", ), 
 "select Col1,count(Col21) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1
  label count(Col2)''"))
```

Comment: hmm, it didn't seem to work. I was able to get what I want, more or less, with

={
query(A1:C5,"select B,count(A) where B <> '' group by B");
"Irrelevant", countif(C2:C,TRUE)
}

but now in case 2 (see test2 on the sheet) I always get Irrelevant = 0 if there is none. Is there a way to filter "irrelevant" if it is 0?